# Two program versions, file associations everywhere

Tags: files, snap, file-association

I have two versions of VSCodium installed - a manual install and a snap install, and they've split file associations between them. I'd like to eliminate the snap version (it's rarely updated): is it possible to have the one I keep inherit its file associations? Will it do that anyway, since the programs are named the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the snap version using the Snap Store or with the command `snap remove <packagename>`. Indeed, file associations will be removed, However, use Files to restore any file associations that you see lacking: in Files, right-click a file of the type you want to associate, then select "Properties" and set your application as "Default" on the "Open with" tab.

Alternatively, removing both versions then reinstalling the one you want will establish the default associations as defined in the software package. User configuration data are preserved upon removal of a package, so you will not loose customizations that way.